FFMPEG burn subtitle to master.m3u8 file
Hey i use ffmpeg to process video into hls stream and generate screenshots using this command
 ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/input.mp4 \
  -vf fps=1/10 thumbnails/thumbnail_%03d.jpg \
  -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 \
  -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 \
  -s:v:0 640x360 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 365k -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k \
  -s:v:1 960x540 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 2000k -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 128k \
  -s:v:2 1280x720 -c:v:2 libx264 -b:v:2 3000k -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 192k \
  -s:v:3 1920x1080 -c:v:3 libx264 -b:v:3 5000k -c:a:3 aac -b:a:3 256k \
  -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2 v:3,a:3" \
  -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
  -f hls -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 \
  -hls_segment_filename "v%v/fileSequence%d.ts" \
  v%v/prog_index.m3u8

But now i need to attach subtitle to the master m3u8 file How do i do that
